# How to remove background noise while performing OpenCV Image subtraction?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have two images one is the document image and the other image is the template image.

[image: Document Image]

[image: Template Image]

I am performing OpenCV image subtraction between document image and template image.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import cv2
template_img = cv2.imread('data_3/template.png')
document_img = cv2.imread('data_3/document.png')
result_img = cv2.subtract(template_img,document_img)
plt.imshow(result_img)
plt.title('Result Image')
plt.show()
```

The Output of the above Program:

[image]

Here the background noise is Apt.no. OpenCV image subtraction has not performed well.

One thing I notice why the image subtraction does not perform well because the quality of both images is not the same. Is there any way to remove the background noise that occurred during image subtraction?

Comment: Use [`cv2.morphologyEx`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#ga67493776e3ad1a3df63883829375201f) with `cv2.MORPH_OPEN`.

Comment: @zindarod I am using cv2.morphologyEx(result_img, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel) and the whole image looks black.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code is self explanatory.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

if __name__ == '__main__':

    image = cv2.imread('image.png',cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    template = cv2.imread('template.png',cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

    kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (3,3))
    template = cv2.morphologyEx(template, cv2.MORPH_ERODE, kernel,iterations = 2)

    image[template == 0] = 255

    cv2.imshow('image', image)
    cv2.imshow('tmpl', template)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image: result]

Comment: The above solution doesn't work with the following document image (https://i.imgur.com/vMKhd9f.png) and template image(https://i.imgur.com/J5IOD9M.png). The needed output(https://i.imgur.com/DhmXHgd.png) and output from the code you provided(https://i.imgur.com/GwMAaJz.png)

Comment: @DineshSonachalam The above method is not for this usage. I've posted an answer to your original question.

Comment: I have done image subtraction cv2.subtract(template,image) in the last line of your code. It works well. This is my output(https://i.imgur.com/ZkrO3zd.png). Thanks for your contribution.

Comment: @DineshSonachalam It worked because your query image was of the exact scale and orientation of your template image. If the query image is a bit scaled up/down or rotated then it won't work. Always try to find a general solution.